# How to create unit test for exceptions in attributes

Tags: c#, unit-testing, attributes

I have attribute class :

```
public class MyAttributeAttribute : Attribute
{
    public MyAttributeAttribute(string proeprty)
    {
        this.TestProperty = proeprty;
    }

    private string property;
    public string TestProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return property;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value.Length > 10)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Lenght of property is longer then 10");
            }
            else
            {
                property = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using it in many methods. As you see it throws exception. I'm creating unit test for this attribute like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void MyTestMethod()
{
    Exception exception = null;
    try
    {
        MyAttributeAttribute myAttributeAttribute = new MyAttributeAttribute("");
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
    {
        exception = ex;
    }

    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(exception, typeof(InvalidOperationException));
}
```

Is it the good way to create unit test for attribute classes? Is there any other ways to create unit test for it?

Comment: You may also use `Assert.Throws`. Anyway asking for "is this style good" is pretty opinion-based.

Comment: Related - [Throwing exceptions from attribute constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24576695/c-sharp-throwing-exceptions-from-attribute-constructor)